# Is there a CSS selector that applies when matching specific values in the URL?

Tags: css, url, css-selectors

Is there a selector that specifies CSS to only applied when matching a specific URL or part of URL?

For example, here is my CSS stylesheet:

```
p {
   color: green;
}

url("home.html") {
   color: blue;
}

url("about.html") {
   color: yellow;
}

path("/path/index*") {
   color: indigo;
}
```

When the user visits home.html I want the home.html selector to be applied. When I'm on the about.html URL I want the about.html to be applied.

CSS media queries allow you to switch to a different set of styles when the width of the view changes. It also lets you specify a different set of styles when the user is going to view on the screen or send it to a printer.

My question again is, "Is it possible to specify a different set of styles depending on the URL or values in the URL." So it's not a question of how to do what I'm asking but if it's possible to.

I am using a CMS and it has a theme that allows you to add your own CSS. There is one stylesheet. That's it. Not two but one.

And I have one page that has specific CSS to that page and only that page. That is the origin of this question. There may be a thousand workarounds but my question is not about the workarounds.

However since this has been answered I do not mind workaround answers related to the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like the `@document` rule was proposed for just this case but it was removed from CSS3 spec and planned for CSS4. From my tests it does not appear to be supported and it's not listed on [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=%40document) at the time of this posting.

The syntax is as follows:

```
@document url("http://www.example.com/widgets/") {
  body {
    color: white;
    background: tomato;
  }
}
/* The above applies styles only to the page at the given URL  */

@document url-prefix("http://www.example.com/widgets/") {
  /* 
  Styles written here are applied to all URLs that 
  begin with 'http://www.example.com/widgets/'  
  */
}

@document regexp("https:.*") {
  /* Styles written here are applied to all URLs that begin with 'https:' */
}
```

---

Test code using **`@media`** query for comparison:

```
var styleTag = document.createElement ("style");
document.head.appendChild (styleTag);
var sheet = styleTag.sheet;
sheet.insertRule ("@media (min-width:600px) { html {color:red}}", 0);
console.log(document.styleSheets.length);
```

Results:

```
// no errors, stylesheet is added
```

---

Test code testing **`@document`** rule:

```
var styleTag = document.createElement ("style");
document.head.appendChild (styleTag);
var sheet = styleTag.sheet;
sheet.insertRule ("@document url('http://www.google.com') { html {color:red}}", 0);
```

Results:

```
/*
Exception: SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified
@Scratchpad/3:4:0
*/
```

---

TIL about @document thanks to @BoltClock

More [info](https://www.quackit.com/css/at-rules/css_document_at-rule.cfm)

Comment: yeah, that was a poorly thought out spec addition, and I'm glad they postponed its inclusion.  It would be better to just have it an attribute on a pseudo-element named document. Like "document[url='http://www.example.com/widgets/']" so that you can use all the normal CSS attribute stuff rather than creating a different set. StartsWith `^=`,  Contains `*=`, EndsWith `$=`, Exactly `=`.  If they want to add regex, then make a new operator available to all attributes, not just this one, maybe `@=`. `%=`, or `regex`?.

Comment: @Robert McKee: Pseudo-elements are [featureless](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#featureless) and cannot have attributes. Plus, you'd be styling the pseudo-element and not the elements being targeted. There's nothing wrong with having an at-document rule IMO - but if a selector is preferred, a pseudo-class that applies to the root element would be a better fit. I don't think there is a way to integrate attribute selector syntax into such a feature without fundamentally redefining attribute selectors (and potentially breaking existing sites in the process).

Comment: @BoltClock I didn't mean pseudo-element as the working group defines it, but as the more generic definition, similar to `:root`, but with the name `document` (or `:document` if you prefer).  Might as well just reuse `:root` as you proposed however.

Comment: @Robert McKee: That would be a pseudo-class, which is not a generic term either ;) (I'm being picky, but the distinction between the two is important.)

Comment: @BoltClock No, I didn't mean a psuedo-class like `p:url(...)` would be.  A fake/mock (to avoid the pseudo name) element that exists at a higher level than the document root. Conceptually being a parent of html element, but as you suggested, a pseudo-class could work as well, allowing the constucts like `nav > a:document-url(...)` but that wouldn't allow the nice attribute selectors either.  But a mock/fake element would allow constructs like `document[url*='example.com'] nav > a { ... }`

Comment: @Robert McKee: Well, that's what at-rules were made for, and why this feature was proposed as an at-document rule and not a selector.

Answer (score 3):

You could attach a `data-url` custom attribute to an element's ancestor, either in the HTML or using JavaScript, and then query that data's value in CSS. Here's a working example where a `data-url` attribute is on the `body` element:

```js
const navigator = document.getElementById('navigator')
const blogUrl = 'https://mywebsite.com/blog';
const aboutUrl = 'https://mywebsite.com/about'

navigator.onclick = () => {
  document.body.dataset.url = document.body.dataset.url === blogUrl ? aboutUrl : blogUrl
};
```

```css
body::before {
  content: "Current url: " attr(data-url);
}

body[data-url*="blog"] .url-based {
  background-color: red;
}

body[data-url*="blog"] .url-based::after {
  content: "You're on the blog page!"
}

.url-based::after {
  content: "You're not on the blog page."
}

#navigator {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.box {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body data-url="https://mywebsite.com/blog">
  <button id="navigator" type="button">Navigate</button>
  <div class="box url-based"></div>
  <div class="box not-url-based">My styling is not based on the current url.</div>
</body>
```

No idea how performant such a solution would be though.

Comment: This is a really creative solution, thank you.

Comment: This is a good solution, especially within PHP based sites: adding something like this to the header template `<body data-url="<?php $url.= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; echo $url; ?>">` will work extremely well.

Answer (score 2):

To be sad there is no pseudo classes to select element's based on URL.The only way you can do it is by adding class to the body tag or specific element and then override the CSS.

Comment: Does your cms not provide any such  class in your body tag or in a wrapping div? What cms?

Comment: @Ideogram I want to know if it's possible. I think URL matching CSS would be a nifty feature to have. If the URL or URL fragment changes (and the page does not reload) then I can have CSS ready that will apply. I'm thinking of rich internet ajax applications.

Answer (score 1):

**if just for only HTML, use jQuery**

```
<script>
        var currentLocation = window.location.pathname;

        if (currentLocation == 'home.html'){
        $('head').append('<link href="home-style.css" rel="stylesheet">');
        } else if (currentLocation == 'about.html'){
        $('head').append('<link href="about-style.css" rel="stylesheet">');
        } else {
        $('head').append('<link href="index-style.css" rel="stylesheet">');
        }
    </script>
```

**If use you WordPress:**

Add your theme function.php

```
  function site_stil_script() {
    
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/YOURPAGE/') {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'theme_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/theme-difrent-style.css', array(), '20120208', 'all' );
    } else {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'theme_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/theme-style.css', array(), '20120208', 'all' );
    }
//other lines....
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'site_stil_script' );
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) has fairly broad support, but maybe not quite high enough to roll out without a fallback. It looks like Firefox will support it very soon, and eventually usage of Chrome older than v105 will drop. See [Can I use...](https://caniuse.com/css-has) & the https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=418039.

Not all webpages will have this, but it's fairly common to have something in the `<head>` containing the URL, e.g.:

- `<link rel="canonical" href>`
- `<meta property="og:url" content>`
- `<meta itemprop="url" content>`
- `<meta name="twitter:url" content>`

Put one of those and `:has()` together and you can write selectors like these:

```css
/* URL ends with "/home.html" */
head:has(link[rel="canonical"][href$="/home.html"]) + body p {
  color: blue;
}

/* URL contains "/path/" */
head:has(link[rel="canonical"][href*="/path/"]) + body p {
  color: indigo;
}
```

---

`$=` & `*=`: [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)
`+`: [next-sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Next-sibling_combinator)

Answer (score 0):

YES !!

For my usecase this is possible with the :target css pseudoclass

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.php

```
<a href="#someid">link to current page (ends up in url after #)</a>
<div id="someid">target of previous link</div>

<style>
    #someid:target {
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>
```

But for your usecase you would need to add to your url something like:
about.html#about
home.html#home